# filter values within an object with object.keys and set a property within to true

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to iterate through objects which match a certain value and then set a property within it to `true`. below is a sample of the data

```js
set() {
    const data = {
        firstName: { checked: false, key: "firstName", tags: ["PERSONAL"] },
        lastName: { checked: false, key: "lastName", tags: ["PERSONAL"] },
        residence: { checked: false, key: "residence", tags: ["CONTACT"] },
        email: { checked: false, key: "email", tags: ["PERSONAL", "CONTACT"] },
        username: { checked: false, key: "username", tags: ["PERSONAL"] },
    };
    let newArray = Object.keys(data).filter((k) =>
        k["tags"].includes("PERSONAL")
    );
    newArray.map((a) => (a.checked = true));
    console.log(newArray);
}
```

I've tried with the above code but it's not working. How do I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Double check what `newArray` is. It’s likely an array of strings (the keys). If so, you cannot set a property of a string.

Comment: Note: If you're not using the array that `map` creates, it's not the right tool to pick. Use `forEach` or a simple loop. Details in [my post here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is probably not the right place to discuss this. But how is creating a new array and pushing modified values to that array better than simply mapping it?

Comment: @Behemoth - That's not what I'm saying above. :-) The code in the question has this standalone statement: `newArray.map(a => a.checked = true)`. That creates a new array and throws it away -- nothing uses the array `map` returns. It's also semantically misleading: It's not a map operation, it's just a loop. `forEach` or a loop would be the more appropriate choice. I love `map` for what it's meant to be used for: Creating a new array of mapped values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to use `Object.values`. Note that `Object.keys` return `firstName, lastname,...` but you need to filter `tag` that appeared in **values** of object.

```js
 const data = {
            "firstName": { "checked": false, "key": "firstName", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] },
            "lastName": { "checked": false, "key": "lastName", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] },
            "residence": { "checked": false, "key": "residence", "tags": ["CONTACT"] },
            "email": { "checked": false, "key": "email", "tags": ["PERSONAL", "CONTACT"] },
            "username": { "checked": false, "key": "username", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] }
        }

        let newArray = Object.values(data).filter(k => k['tags'].includes('PERSONAL'))

        newArray.map(a => a.checked = true)
        console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Even though the OP did it, I recommend **not** misusing `map` like that ([details](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/)). If not using the array it creates, use `forEach` or a simple loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right and thanks for your help. But I think OP's focus is in Object keys and values. But still you are right we can use `forEach` for simple loop

Comment: i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: @BenjaminBlay my snippet is working correctly please check your code with the snippet

Comment: @BenjaminBlay - Are you sure you used `Object.values` as shown in the answer, not `Object.keys` as in the question?

Comment: @BenjaminBlay Has your problem been solved? If not share your code to advice

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, i was missing tags, it is working perfectly now... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the `Object.values()` not just over `Object.keys()`, then map over these values and check whether `tags` includes `"PERSONAL"`. If that is the case return a new object with property `checked: true` otherwise return the initial item.
Finally remove the items with `checked: false` with a simple `fitler()`.

```js
const data = {
  firstName: {
    checked: false,
    key: "firstName",
    tags: ["PERSONAL"],
  },
  lastName: {
    checked: false,
    key: "lastName",
    tags: ["PERSONAL"],
  },
  residence: {
    checked: false,
    key: "residence",
    tags: ["CONTACT"],
  },
  email: {
    checked: false,
    key: "email",
    tags: ["PERSONAL", "CONTACT"],
  },
  username: {
    checked: false,
    key: "username",
    tags: ["PERSONAL"],
  },
  testItemWithoutTags: {
    checked: true,
    key: "testItemWithoutTags",
  },
};

const result = Object.values(data)
  .filter((k) => k.tags && k.tags.includes("PERSONAL"))
  .map((k) => ({ ...k,
    checked: true
  }));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: @BenjaminBlay - Are you sure you used `Object.values` as shown in the answer, not `Object.keys` as you did in the question?

Comment: My provided code snippet should work perfectly fine. Are you using my code with another data-set? Because that error should only happen when there are no `tags` on an item. If so just do another check if `tags` exist. (Im going to adapt my answer)

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` gives you an array of the *keys* of the object (`"firstName"`, etc.), not the values. You're then trying to use a `tags` property on that string, which won't work.

You could use `Object.values`, `filter`, and a loop afterward, but that's multiple trips through the object/values for no particularly good reason (one for `Object.values`, another for `filter`, and a third for setting `checked`). Instead, just use a single loop:

```
let newArray = [];
for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];
    if (value.tags.includes("PERSONAL")) {
        value.checked = true;
        newArray.push(value);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    "firstName": { "checked": false, "key": "firstName", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] },
    "lastName": { "checked": false, "key": "lastName", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] },
    "residence": { "checked": false, "key": "residence", "tags": ["CONTACT"] },
    "email": { "checked": false, "key": "email", "tags": ["PERSONAL", "CONTACT"] },
    "username": { "checked": false, "key": "username", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] }
};
let newArray = [];
for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];
    if (value.tags.includes("PERSONAL")) {
        value.checked = true;
        newArray.push(value);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

---

Note that both your original attempted solution and the above **modify** the objects that are in your `data` object (by changing their `checked` property). If that's what you meant to do, great, but if you meant to create new objects instead, here's the above doing that via spread syntax:

```
let newArray = [];
for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];
    if (value.tags.includes("PERSONAL")) {
        newArray.push({...value, checked: true});
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    "firstName": { "checked": false, "key": "firstName", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] },
    "lastName": { "checked": false, "key": "lastName", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] },
    "residence": { "checked": false, "key": "residence", "tags": ["CONTACT"] },
    "email": { "checked": false, "key": "email", "tags": ["PERSONAL", "CONTACT"] },
    "username": { "checked": false, "key": "username", "tags": ["PERSONAL"] }
};
let newArray = [];
for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];
    if (value.tags.includes("PERSONAL")) {
        newArray.push({...value, checked: true});
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

Take advantage of comma and ternary operator:

```
const data = {"firstName":{"checked":false,"key":"firstName","tags":["PERSONAL"]},
"lastName":{"checked":false,"key":"lastName","tags":["PERSONAL"]},
"residence":{"checked":false,"key":"residence","tags":["CONTACT"]},
"email":{"checked":false,"key":"email","tags":["PERSONAL", "CONTACT"]},
"username":{"checked":false,"key":"username","tags":["PERSONAL"]}
}

let arr = Object.values(data).filter(e => {
    let isPersonal = e.tags.includes("PERSONAL")
    return ( isPersonal ? e.checked = true : null, isPersonal )
})

console.log(arr)
```